# Описание в django model

Tags: python, django

У меня есть модель и я хочу, чтобы в админке было небольшое описание, по типу для чего и как использовать.
Возможно ли это сделать?
[image: Хочу чтобы рядом было описание]

Comment: https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/ref/models/fields.html#help-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно просто можно определить в модели вот так

```py
your_filed = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Please use the following format: blabl@mail.com")
```

Если владеете англ., то здесь [документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#help-text)

Comment: А можно сделать описание не только для одного поля, а на всю модель?

Comment: @Timofey конечно можно, но здесь уже зависит, как это будет выглядеть и кастомизация будет ручками, т.е. кастомизировать представление admin панели. Не знаю на сколько это вообще актуально,  если можно просто статический текст добавить для страницы